# MoviePy ImageClip randomly producing grey videos

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to create a simple video of one image with audio with MoviePy. Working with the same code, sometimes MoviePy randomly produces greyed out and glitched videos like this:[image: greyed out video] (opened with VLC Media Player)

The audio works fine in the final video, and the image used is also completely fine.
I tried searching but couldn't find anything that worked. I also re-downloaded `FFMPEG`, thinking it would solve the problem, but to no advantage.

The code I am using is:

```py
# assume aud_path, vid_path and out_path are set and imports have been done
aud_clip = AudioFileClip(aud_path)
vid_clip = ImageClip(vid_path)
vid_clip = vid_clip.set_audio(aud_clip).set_duration(aud_clip.duration)
vid_clip.write_videofile(out_path, temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", fps=24)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! For anyone having a similar problem, the problem was in the `vid_clip.write_videfile()` method in the `codec` argument.

I changed the `codec` to `"mpeg4"` and it is working fine now.